# SQL Last order per client

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table dbo.tbl_orders where i collect data as:

```
Date
clientName
Amount
```

How do I create a view where I can see per client, the date of their last order?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW last_client_order_date as
SELECT ClientName, max(Date) 
FROM tbl_orders
GROUP BY ClientName
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting latest order date per client

```
select [ClientId], max([Date]) from [Orders] group by [ClientId]
```

#### Getting latest order per client

simply join the query above with the orders tables

```
select * from [Orders] 
join ( select [Clientid], max([Date]) from [Orders] group by [ClientId] ) as [LatestOrders] 
on [LatestOrders].Date = [Orders].Date 
and [LatestOrders].[ClientId] = [Orders].[ClientId]
```

> **Note:** you may get multiple orders per client in case two orders have the same date

Comment: Neither the columns nor the table name match the question.

Comment: @Yuck, SO is not about answering specific closed questions as much as resolving the conceptual problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I am using sql-server. The Group By in combination with the Max Date works. 

Now that this works - I would like to see also the amount of the last order placed. The issue is that once I just add the dbo.tbl_orders.amount to the select statement, I get of course again all data. How do I get to see the amount only related to the last order?

Comment: @Johan I've updated my answer according to your comment

Comment: Thanks for your help and responses!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this, but is this what you need?

```
Select * 
FROM dbo.tbl_orders 
WHERE clientName = value 
AND Date = (select max(Date) 
   from dbo.tbl_orders 
   where clientName = value)
```

`value`being the clientName you are looking for

Comment: I think he wants all clients, so 
Select * 
FROM dbo.tbl_orders 
WHERE Date = (select max(Date) 
   from dbo.tbl_orders 
   )